# How to get date from another book in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date, get, cell

I have problem with getting date from cells of another book to my opened book where vba code is. Instead of that I get replacing cells on value of next cell in anoter workbook after one being opened.

Where is the problem can arise from?

My code is below

```
Sub Example1()
    Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    'open the workbook with data
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Medvedevda\Documents\excel\date_copy_main.xlsx")
    'read the data from the first columns
    For i = 1 To 9
        Cells(i, 1) = _
            objWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    'close the workbook
    objWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to define your current range that you're changing. Right now your active workbook will be the one you opened up. Therefor (since you're not clarifying which worksheet `Cells(i,1)` is from) VBA will assume the `Cells(i,1)` to be from said ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: That's the reason why you should always be explicit when referencing cells. When you open the workbook, it became the active one. `Cells(i,1)` is defaulting to the active workbook, hence the last opened. Use `ThisWorkbook.Cells(i,1)` instead (`ThisWorkbook` is the one containing the code) .

Comment: @VincentG Yes, also specify the sheet, for the same reasons : using sheet index `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1)` or name `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried to reference to workbook explicit with ThisWorksheet but got deleteng cells in cycle instead of copieng date in my target book. I wanted to say that I need to take my date from opening book with date (objWorkbook) in result code and add them in my target book where the code is starting from. That is I have opened target book and I want to open another book ((objWorkbook) with code then copy date from one and insert them to target book.